# Delete a contract using using delete_account method from class ContractPromiseBatch near-sdk-core

Tags: nearprotocol

**TLDR**:
What is the correct way to do a cross-contract call from parent account `sub.myacc.testnet` to delete a sub-account `one.sub.myacc.testnet` using `delete_account` on `ContractPromiseBatch` from `near-sdk-core` without getting permission error

**Full Explanation**:
From the command line I make sure I am logged in:
`near login` account `myacc.testnet`

I created the following subaccount to where I deploy the factory contract:

`near create-account sub.myacc.testnet --masterAccount myacc.testnet`

I then deploy my factory contract using:
`near deploy`

Using `near-sdk-core`, this factory contract has a function that creates, deploys a contract and adds a `full_access_key` using `ContractPromiseBatch`

Like this:

```
 ContractPromiseBatch
  .create("one.sub.myacc.testnet")
  .create_account()
  .transfer(u128.from(100))
  .add_full_access_key(base58.decode(context.senderPublicKey))
  .deploy_contract(code)
```

I then make sure all accounts have the right keys with `near keys <accountId>`

`near keys sub.myacc.testnet`

```
[
  {
    access_key: { nonce: 84008729000009, permission: 'FullAccess' },
    public_key: 'ed25519:gu5xxxxxxxxxxxx'
  }
]
```

`near keys one.sub.myacc.testnet`

```
[
  {
    access_key: { nonce: 84009033000000, permission: 'FullAccess' },
    public_key: 'ed25519:gu5xxxxxxxxxxxx'
  }
]
```

Both keys match.

I then add the key to our main account to make sure all accounts have same access:

`near add-key myacc.testnet gu5xxxxxx`

If I attempt to delete the contract `one.sub.myacc.testnet` with the following command:
`near delete one.sub.myacc.testnet <beneficiary>`

I get the following error:
`Unable to find [ testnet ] credentials for [ one.sub.myacc.testnet ]...`

If I check `~/.near-credentials/testnet`
I see that I do indeed have `myacc.testnet.json` file with the key we added but I don't see either `sub.myacc.testnet.json` or `one.sub.myacc.testnet.json`

So I manually added:
`one.sub.myacc.testnet.json` and copy the key

This will work:
`Deleting account. Account id: one.sub.myacc.testnet`

**Error**:
Now, I have a function in the factory contract where I try to use `delete_account` method  and sign it with either `sub.myacc.testnet`, `one.sub.myacc.testnet`, or `myacc.testent`

```
ContractPromiseBatch.create(one.sub.myacc.testent) 
    .delete_account(one.sub.myacc.testent)
```

I get the following error:
`Error: Actor sub.myacc.testent doesn't have permission to account one.sub.myacc.testnet to complete the action`

From the docs:
`Subaccounts work exactly like standalone accounts, meaning that after creation, the parent account no longer has any special control or access to the subaccount.`

I would think that the parent account could control the subaccount if it has the full access key? If so, I am missing a step or a way to call `ContractPromiseBatch` with the correct `full_access_key` but can't find an example of how this should be done.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

> Error: Actor sub.myacc.**testent** doesn't have permission to account one.sub.myacc.testnet to complete the action

Hey, I hope this is just bad redaction, but if that's not the case, maybe your problem is **testent** instead of testnet.

Answer (score 1):

Accounts have **no power** over their sub-accounts. In practice, they work as completely different and **independent** accounts, the only benefit of sub-accounts is that they allow you to better organize your accounts.

With that being said, the **sub account is the only one that can delete itself**. However, you could add a method to your subaccount that only the parent account can call that makes the subaccount delete itself ([reference](https://near-docs.io/develop/contracts/actions#delete-account)).